# Unable to run 'grails war' due to hibernate error

Tags: hibernate, grails

I'm trying to run 'grails war' on Linux but I'm getting:

```
Could not initialize class org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
at DataSource$_run_closure3_closure6_closure11.class$(DataSource.groovy)
```

I've tried the usual 'grails clean' step and i've even deleted .grails, .java and .groovy from my home directory but to no avail.

Note: grails war runs ok on my OS X machine.

Has anyone experienced this before? And did you find a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the problem was caused by me using the console i.e.

```
grails> clean
grails> war
```

failed however

```
$ grails clean
$ grails war
```

works. I'll try to find the root cause for this but for the moment I've worked around the problem